# How to set value to array textfield using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

Sorry, I don't know what is correct question for this case.

I have an array textfield which has keypress event to calls jQuery function.

Here is my textfield:

```
<input type="text" id="idnya['+k+']" onkeypress="return $(this).fsearch()" />
```

It runs a query from a function to shows some rows on this div:

```
<div id="divResult" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Everytime I click one of rows, the row filled into my array textfield(s).
Anyway I have succeed to fill one textfield but how if I add other textfield.
What should i change in this function?

```
!function (e) {
e.fn.fsearch = function () {
    var t = e(this);
    $resultDiv = e("#divResult"), t.focus(), t.addClass("searchi"), $resultDiv.html("<ul></ul><div id='search-footer' class='searchf'></div>"), t.keyup(function (i) {
        function a(e, t) {
            e.removeClass("selected"), e.eq(t).addClass("selected")
        }
        var s = e(this).val();
        if ("" != s) {
            var n = e(".selected").index(),
                o = $resultDiv.find(".option"),
                r = o.length;
            if (40 == i.keyCode) r > n + 1 && (n++, a(o, n));
            else if (38 == i.keyCode) n > 0 && (n--, a(o, n));
            else if (13 == i.keyCode) {
                $resultDiv.find("ul li.selected").attr("id");
                var l = $resultDiv.find("ul li.selected").find(".name").text(),
                    c = $resultDiv.find("ul li.selected").find(".atm").text();

                t.val(l),  e("#atm").val(c), $resultDiv.fadeOut()  
            } else $resultDiv.fadeIn(), $resultDiv.find("#search-footer").html("<img src='img/loader.gif' alt='Collecting Data...'/>"), e.getJSON("<?php base_url(); ?>/Mycontroller/searchjson", {
                searchword: s
            }, function (e) {
                for (var t = "", i = 0; i < e.length; i++) t += "<li id=" + e[i].TermId + ' class="option"><span class="name">' + e[i].TermId + '</span><br/><span class="atm" style="font-size:9px;">' + e[i].AtmLocation + "</span></li>";
                $resultDiv.find("ul").empty().prepend(t), $resultDiv.find("div#search-footer").text(e.length + " results found..."), $resultDiv.find("ul li").first().addClass("selected")
            }), $resultDiv.find("ul li").live("mouseover", function () {
                n = $resultDiv.find("ul li").index(this), o = $resultDiv.find(".option"), a(o, n)
            })
        } else $resultDiv.hide()
    }), jQuery(document).live("click", function (t) {
        var i = e(t.target);
        i.hasClass("searchi") || i.hasClass("searchf") || $resultDiv.fadeOut()
    }), t.click(function () {
        var i = e(this).val();
        "" != i && $resultDiv.fadeIn(), t.val("") && e("#atm").val("")
    }), $resultDiv.find("li").live("click", function () {
        e(this).attr("id");
        var i = e(this).find(".name").text();
        t.val(i);
       var a = e(this).find(".atm").text();
        e("#atm").val(a)
    })
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: okey thanks, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be what your looking for if i understood your question correctly

```
$('tr').on('click', function(e) {
     $('tr').removeClass('selected');
     $(this).addClass('selected');

    $(':text').each(function(index) {
        $(this).val($('.selected')[0].children[index].innerText);    
    });

 });
```

here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/pixelchemist/5P2Bf/